# MYSQL Query Performance with Distinct, order by and limit against same table

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a query that is forcing a full index scan against an innodb table - which is expected, however, the performance is still much slower than expected.  The table has a structure like:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key
CUSTOMER_ID int(11) NO  MUL
CustLatitude    decimal(15,12)  YES 
CustLongitude   decimal(15,12)  YES 
StoreLatitude   decimal(15,12)  NO  
StoreLongitude  decimal(15,12)  NO  
StoreID int(11) NO  MUL
Distance    double  YES MUL
```

For each CUSTOMER_ID I am selecting the row that contains the minimum Distance value as follows:

```
select 
distinct(CUSTOMER_ID) as incustid, 
(select StoreID from CustomerStoreDistance where CUSTOMER_ID = incustid 
    order by Distance ASC limit 1) as closeststoreid 
from
CustomerStoreDistance;
```

As shown above, there are indexes on CUSTOMER_ID, Distance and StoreID.     There are approximately 43M rows in the CustomerStoreDistance table and running on RDS with a db.cr1.8xlarge class machine with 244 GB of RAM and 32vCPUs.

The parameters have been optimized to the best of my knowledge for sorting, temp space, etc. however, am curious if there is a better way and/or more optimizations.

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: Prefix the query with explain and see what the plan is, add it to your question if you want. When you say you have three indexes, is that as well as the primary key?

Comment: You should definitely run an EXPLAIN and make sure this isn't effectively a Cartesian Join when you run it... I have a similar table and the explain statement basically indicated that this thing would cross product the table with itself. It may be different with whatever indices you have. I don't know. I do know, however, this essentially what you want is a window (aka analytic) function. And there is a great article on using those here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/selecting-a-specific-non-aggregated-column-data-in-group-by I'd take a look, and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would do much better if you had a separate customer table.  In any case, try this version of the query:

```
select incustid,
       (select StoreId
        from CustomerStoreDistinct csd2
        where csd2.CustomerId = csd.incustid
        order by distance
        limit 1
       ) as ClosestStoreId
from (select distinct CustomerId as incustid
      from CustomerStoreDistance
     ) csd;
```

The subquery is to help avoid confusion between the `distinct` and the subquery.  I think MySQL will execute the subquery before the distinct, and that is just wasted effort.

To optimize this query, you want a composite index on `CustomerStoreDistance(CustomerId, Distance, StoreId)`.

EDIT:

Because these queries already require an aggregation to eliminate duplicates, this might work better:

```
select CustomerId,
       substring_index(group_concat(StoredId order by Distance), ',', 1) as ClosestStoreId
from CustomerStoreDistance
group by CustomerId;
```

Comment: Both queries worked wonderfully!  Many thanks - that's a very useful way to trick MySQL in handling the distinct correctly.